# Quadratic that yields the longest prime sequence?

Tags: prime-numbers

The quadratic $n^2+n+41$ yields prime numbers all the way up to $n=40$ before it fails (pretty cool!).

My question is: **Do you know of a quadratic that can 'last even longer'?**

Comment: Note that the Green-Tao theorem tells us that there are arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions in the primes, which would relate to the linear case.

Comment: Also, to add to this, is it just a coincidence that the number of positive integer terms that this quadratic lasts HAPPENS to be one less than the constant term?

Comment: Not really a conincidence. It's obvious that $n^2+n+41$ is not prime when $n=41$.

Comment: That is true, but unless I am missing something, it is not completely obvious that the prime-producing property necessarily fails precisely at $n-1$.

Comment: $n^2+n+a$ fails to be prime for $n=a-1$: $(a-1)^2+(a-1)+a=a^2$

Comment: I can understand that $n-1$ doesn't work, but my question was more so targeted towards the property that every $n$ less than or equal to $n-2$ generates primes.

Comment: @Trogdor Actually, this is closely related to the fact that $e^{\pi\sqrt{4\cdot 41-1}}$ is *very* close to an integer!

Comment: From where did you manage to pull that expression from? Wow!

Answer (score 2):

$$36n^2-810n+2753$$

is prime for $n\le44$ ([source](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prime-GeneratingPolynomial.html)).

Answer (score 1):

$$n^2-81n+1681$$
is prime for all natrual numbers $\le 80$. (This is of course an unfair answer)

Comment: This is the OP's polynomial in disguise, and yields the same primes, though more often :)

Answer (score 0):

From Sierpsinski's prime sequence theorem  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SierpinskisPrimeSequenceTheorem.html you can find arbitrarily many primes   (but maybe not  consecutive values of the quadratic).